# Use to_json but with overall data name

Tags: python, arrays, json, pandas, to-json

I'm trying to use `to_json` to create a json file with python. I have it working so far to produce the following sort of output:

```
[
    {
        "Country": "A",
        "Title": "B",
        "Category": "C"
    },
    {
        "Country": "D",
        "Title": "E",
        "Category": "F"
    }
]
```

But I need it to create a json file that looks like this. Quite simply, to add the "data" name. Any tips on how to do so?

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "Country": "A",
            "Title": "B",
            "Category": "C"
        },
        {
            "Country": "D",
            "Title": "E",
            "Category": "F"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think `.to_json()` can do this by itself. Use `df.to_dict('records')` to create the list of dictionaries, then put that list inside another dictionary and write that JSON to the file.

```
d = {"data": df.to_dict('records')}
with open("file.json", "w") as f:
    json.dump(d, f)
```

Comment: This works, thanks @Barmar. I've marked this answer as correct but if you know of a way with .to_json too, that would be cool.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you just create a dictionary and add your output (list) as a value which 'data' is its key and dump it to make a json format?!

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).

Comment: i know... but i need more reputation to write comment! but it is not far from the an answer @Barmar

Comment: Obviously I know that, I wrote it in my comment. A good answer should show how to do it, not just describe it in vague terms.

Comment: i know you knew it! it is an answer yeah it cant be compared with yours! obviously you have more experience in answering questions. thanks for your guidance @Barmar

Answer (score -1):

> orient str 
> Indication of expected JSON string format.
> ‘records’ : list like [{column -> value}, … , {column -> value}]

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html?highlight=to_json#pandas.DataFrame.to_json

```
df.to_json(....., orient='records')
```

Comment: How does that add the `data` key?

Comment: Thanks! But this is what I already am using. The key difference is that I need it to show up as having 'data' as the name there.